# How do I make absolute positioned assets responsive, is it a matter of endless media queries?

Tags: css

I'm a bit stumped on the appropriate way to make this example responsive, is it just a matter of securing both objects in one container and using margins so they don't interfere with the text on the left and media queries to address movement?

Is using IMG tags the preferred way to achieve this result or should the background curved image, be border-radius or a pseudo SVG?

Thanks for your assistance, I'd love a nudge in the right direction if possible.

[Example of Mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCnBg.jpg)
[Example of Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4DdA.jpg)
https://codepen.io/CreamOnCats/pen/YzQzOqK

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

section {
  background: #EAEAEA;
  position: relative;
}

.col-x2-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, auto);
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}

/* Inner Divs */

.col-x2-grid div {
  position: relative;
  grid-rows: span 1;
}

.col-x2-grid div:nth-child(1) {
  padding: 1.5em;
}

.col-x2-grid div:nth-child(2) {
  height: 100vh;
}

/* Shapes */

.shape-bg {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.shape-fg {
  position: absolute;
  right: 25%;
  top: 5%;
  width: 200px;
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .col-x2-grid {
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
  .col-x2-grid div {
    position: relative;
    grid-column: span 1;
  }
  /* Inner Divs */
  .col-x2-grid div:nth-child(1) {
    padding: 10em;
  }
  .col-x2-grid div:nth-child(2) {
    height: 800px;
  }
  /* Shapes */
  .shape-bg {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .shape-fg {
    position: absolute;
    right: 55%;
    top: 25%;
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="col-x2-grid">
    <div>Nam velit sapien, faucibus ac sapien vel, volutpat vulputate magna. Pellentesque viverra scelerisque sapien a laoreet. Suspendisse potenti.</div>
    <div>
      <img class="shape-bg" src="https://dummyimage.com/500x800/F53851000">
      <img class="shape-fg" src="https://dummyimage.com/250x400/FFF000">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: What do you want it to look like on narrow viewports?

Comment: @AHaworth That is my fault, sorry I wasn't clear. I've just added an image link in the post as well. https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCnBg.jpg

Thanks mate, I appreciate it!

Comment: Is the (black) image always to have a fixed aspect ratio (e.g. so the whole image is always shown) or is the aspect ratio to change with the aspect ratio of the viewport (so sometimes only part of the image will be shown)?

Comment: @AHaworth Preferably the whole black image is always there in full display, the item is going to be a picture of a phone i'd like to show, if the curvature could be shown above and below at all times would be ideal.

Is it possible to use a vertical section divider (curve svg) and just make the entire right div pink, then offset the phone with position: absolute. Or will CSS Grid conflict with that?

Comment: Have you considered radial gradient for the red part-circle as a background image. It doesn't seem to have particular meaning, just decorative so it would make sense to have it as a background image rather than as an element in the HTML.

Comment: @bleenwithcream I think [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lPJVi797Uy0) might be useful in finding a solution

Comment: @AHaworth Thank you so much, I'm going to play around with this now but it looks like it solves everything. I can't upvote your answer yet but once it let's me, I will solve this post! I appreciate your help!

Comment: @RifkyNiyas Oh cheers, that looks pretty interesting, I'll watch it now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet with some ideas for getting the required layout.

Looking at the images given in the question it seems the red part-circle is decorative and so does not necessarily have to be within the main content. The image of the phone though seems to have meaning as obviously does the text.

This snippet also does just one media query, to distinguish between landscape mode - when the two parts are on the same level, and portrait mode when the two parts are given equal width and the image and red circle are under the text part with the image centered.

The red part-circle is provided by a pseudo element simply because I found that easier to position than a radial-gradient background. The image is positioned absolutely. I didn't find using grid or flex particularly useful so used the 'old' method of centering with positioning and translations.

Obviously you will want to play with exact dimensions and also what font size maximum and maybe minimum you will allow.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100vw;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  font-size: max(1.5vw, 1rem);
}

.wrapper::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 90%;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 90%;
  left: 60%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  background: #f53851;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.part.one {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
}

.part.two {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
}

.one .content {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.thebutton {
  color: white;
  background-color: #f53851;
  padding: 5px;
}

.image {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 20%;
  height: auto;
  top: 50%;
  left: 60%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

@media (orientation: portrait) {
  .wrapper::before {
    left: 50%;
    top: 75%;
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
    z-index: -1;
  }
  .part.one,
  .part.two {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
  }
  .part.one {
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: white;
  }
  .one .content {
    width: max(50vw, 250px)
  }
  .image {
    top: 75%;
    left: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="part one">
    <div class="content">Nam velit sapien, faucibus ac sapien vel, volutpat vulputate magna. Pellentesque viverra scelerisque sapien a laoreet. Suspendisse potenti.
      <div><button class="thebutton">BUTTON</button></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="part two">
  </div>
  <img class="image" src="https://dummyimage.com/250x400/FFF000" />
</div>
```